# Vararg as table parameter - OpenL-Tablets

Tags: java

This question is specific to [OpenL-Tablets](http://openl-tablets.org/) (no tag currently exists)

In trying to abstract code from business users creating rules through the creation of a Method table which will take variable number of objects.

[image: Method table]

However when trying to use the varargs parameter, the following error is thrown:

> Parsing Error: Error: Encountered " "..." "... "" at line 1, column 45. Was expecting one of: "[" ...  ...
>
> Openl Code Fragment:
>   ======================= ResolvedResponse setResolvedResponse(Section... section) ^^^^^^^

How else can this be achieved without having to explicitly create a method with x number of arguments?

Since OpenL's aim is to remain business analyst friendly, we are advised to abstract things such that a BA would never need to work with a structure such as `setResolvedReponse(`**new Section[]{section1, section2, section3}**`)` as it requires some knowledge of Java syntax. Perhaps there is another way the parameter must to be formatted such that it understands the vararg type properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare as an array.

```
setResolvedResponse(Section[] secs)
```

So instead of:

```
setResolvedResponse(obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

Call:

```
setResolvedResponse(new String[]{ obj1, obj2, obj3})
```

Comment: That was an option. However since OpenL's aim is to remain BA friendly, we need to abstract things such that a BA would never need to work with a structure in such a way as it requires some knowledge of Java syntax. Perhaps you know another way or how the parameter needs to be formatted such that it understands the vararg type properly?

Comment: An array is not a java syntax, but you can ommit the new array creation also

Comment: I'm sorry, that syntax isn't valid - you must declare the array type. What version of the product are you using?